# How did this old SQL query work without a join in the subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the T-SQL. The code has been around for years and it was handed to me to migrate to another SQL server. It apparently works, but I don't know why. The execution plan doesn't show any predicates being used, so how does it know which rows to exclude. If I run the subquery I get 1146 rows with the value 1

```
SELECT EM.PERSON_ID 
FROM EMP_BEN_ELECTS EBE, EMPLOYEE_MAP EM 
WHERE EBE.BW_ID = EM.BW_ID 
      AND CHANGE_BENEFIT_EVENT_DATE IS NULL 
      AND OPTION_ID <> 'WAIVE' 
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EMPLOYEE_BILLING WHERE BILLING_GROUPING_ID 
                    IN('HWMONTHLY','HWINDIVIDUALBILLED') AND END_DATE IS NULL)
```

I plan rewrite it without the subquery and use a left join instead, but this just boggled me that it works. The only time I seen code written like this without the join being qualified was when I seen code coming from an Oracle developer.

Comment: I think your concern about the subquery and the complete lack of correlation to the main query is well founded. Seems highly suspicious to me. No one but the people responsible for this code base can offer insight into that topic.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery of `NOT EXISTS` is not used to return any (of the 1146) rows.

It is used to check if at least 1 row exists in the table `EMPLOYEE_BILLING` with the specified conditions:

```
BILLING_GROUPING_ID IN('HWMONTHLY','HWINDIVIDUALBILLED') AND END_DATE IS NULL
```

If there is such a row, then `NOT EXISTS` returns `FALSE` and since all the conditions in the `WHERE` clause of the main query are linked with the operator `AND`, then the final result is `WHERE FALSE`, making the query to not return any rows.

Don't rewrite the query with a `LEFT` join.
`EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` provide usually better performance than joins.

What you must change though, is that archaic join syntax with the `,`.

Change it to a proper `INNER` join with an `ON` clause:

```
SELECT EM.PERSON_ID 
FROM EMP_BEN_ELECTS EBE INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_MAP EM 
ON EBE.BW_ID = EM.BW_ID 
WHERE CHANGE_BENEFIT_EVENT_DATE IS NULL 
  AND OPTION_ID <> 'WAIVE' 
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM EMPLOYEE_BILLING 
    WHERE BILLING_GROUPING_ID IN('HWMONTHLY','HWINDIVIDUALBILLED') 
      AND END_DATE IS NULL
  )
```

Also, you should qualify all the column names with the table's name/alias they belong to (`CHANGE_BENEFIT_EVENT_DATE` and `OPTION_ID` which I left unqualified because I don't know which alias to use).

Comment: Thank you for the response I did rewrite the code to match our standards.

Comment: _I did rewrite the code to match our standards_ - booo :)

Comment: I think in my mind it should be explicit about what doesn't exist in the subquery. Does the person not have billing info, does the person's account not exist.... It could just be and not exists (SELECT 1)

Comment: @PhillipPutzback I don't know the requirement, so I don't know the logic behind the subquery. What I tried to explain in my answer is what is the purpose of `NOT EXISTS (...)`.